# do-realease-update aborte due to insufficient space in /var/cache/apt/archives

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I want to update from 20.04 to the next lts release with do-release-upgrade utility. But the process aborted with the following message:

```
Not enough free disk space 

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 1,755 M free 
space on disk '/var/cache/apt/archives'. Please free at least an 
additional 182 M of disk space on '/var/cache/apt/archives'.
```

Having a look to the /var/cache/apt/archives, it appears that the folder is empty. This is confirmed by a df -h  which shows that 100% of the space is available:

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                      1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /var/cache/apt/archives
```

What can I do to complete the upgrade process?

Comment: Your output told you what to do: Free up at least 182MB of additional storage space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need free space on the `tmpfs` mounting point, but rather on the `/var` mounting point (which may itself be a sub-directory of the root mounting point `/`).

Use `df-mh` to check if your root partition `/` has enough free space. If not, free some. You will probably need a lot more than 182M to finish the installation of the distribution upgrade.

Comment: The df command shows enough available space on the lvm partition mount on /. And after updating the kernel to the last one, the do-realease-upgrade shows an additional disk space issue on /boot, also there is enough space. So the problem seems to be somewhere else. Thank you for the hint.